# What's the difference between Regular Tasks & File Tasks in Rake

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm currently looking into using Rake to deploy my projects and I'm beavering away at learning Ruby/Rake. However can someone please explain to me the difference between Regular Tasks & File Tasks? This keeps getting mentioned but I have no idea the difference between the two and I can't find a definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Martin Fowler wrote a great explanation of these features.

- http://martinfowler.com/articles/rake.html#RakeTasks
- http://martinfowler.com/articles/rake.html#FileTasks

> ### File Tasks
>
> The tasks I talked about above are similar to tasks in ant. Rake also supports a slightly different kind of task called a file task which is closer to the notion of tasks in make. Here's another example, slightly simplified, from my web site rakefile.
>
> ```
> file 'build/dev/rake.html' => 'dev/rake.xml' do |t|
>   require 'paper'
>   maker = PaperMaker.new t.prerequisites[0], t.name
>   maker.run
> end
> ```
>
> With a file you are referring to actual files rather than task names. So 'build/dev/rake.html' and 'dev/rake.xml' are actual files. The html file is the output of this task and the xml file is the input. You can think of a file task as telling the build system how to make the output file - indeed this is exactly the notion in make - you list the output files you want and tell make how to make them.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/FileTask.html):

> A FileTask is a task that includes time based dependencies. If any of a FileTask‘s prerequisites have a timestamp that is later than the file represented by this task, then the file must be rebuilt (using the supplied actions).

Answer (score 0):

File task check the creation date of the 'task-file' and the prerequistes.

Example:

```
task 'xx.txt' => 'xx.dat' do
  p :x
end
```

`xx.txt` is executed always.

```
file 'xx.txt' => 'xx.dat' do
  p :x
end
```

`xx.txt` is only executed, if `xx.dat` is younger then `xx.txt` (or if `xx.txt` does not exist yet)

In both cases the file (or task) `xx.dat` must exist.